# Custom attributes errors in phoenix framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

When I have some validation errors in the changeset I want to be able to say to the end user: "**credit card** can't be blank", or something more complex such as: "**your awesome credit card** can't be blank".

In short I want the same feature of that: http://gothamjs.io/documentation/1.0.0/validator#change-attributes

I didn't find on the guides something like that, so I came up with that:

**error_helpers.ex**

```
  @doc """
  Generates tag for inlined form input errors.
  """
  def error_tag(form, field) do
    if error = form.errors[field] do
      content_tag :span,  to_string(field) <> " " <> translate_error(error), class: "help-block"
    end
  end
```

> You can see I just added **to_string(field)**

I guess I can come up with an hacky solution with gettext, to translate the field to reach my goal, but I think it's a big no-no to do that.

Doesn't phoenix provide something similar out of the box ?
If not, what's the best way to tackle that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using generators to check how Phoenix does that:

```
mix phoenix.gen.html User users name credit_card
```

To add errors you need to check two places. First one is model. In changeset function you can add:

```
validate_length(:credit_card, min: 1, message: "your awesome credit card...")
```

This will add validation error to `:credit_card` field with given message when it is empty.

Second one is template: you need to use:

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @actoin, fn f -> %>
  <%= if @changeset.action do %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <p>Something wrong</p>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label f, :credit_card %>
    <%= text_input f, :credit_card %>
    <%= error_tag f, :credit_card %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The `error_tag` will make sure that your error appears where it should. If you need to translate the error message you can use `gettext` inside model.

You probably don't have to touch generated controller.

Comment: This is neat, but it doesn't offer the option at add classes to the paragraph element the error_tag generates.

Comment: Not necessarily. The `error_tag` is a pre generated function in `ErrorHelpers`. If for some field you need special treatment, you can add clauses like `def error_tag(form, :my_custom_field) do` and return whatever HTML you need.
Alternatively, you can drop the usage of `error_tag` and inline the error message. I believe the logic that shows is depends on class `invalid-feedback`.